# Show hidden form field if className is present

Tags: javascript

So I'm building out my form and I have both client side validation (Bootstrap 4 Validator) and server side validation using PHP.

I've coded out the below script to hide the form unless the value is "CA".

```
const formWrapperState = document.getElementById('contactForm');

var field = document.getElementById('resident');
function handler() {
    if (field.value !== 'CA') {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        formWrapperState.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
field.addEventListener('change', handler);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
handler();
```

Once my client side form submits successfully, it then reloads and repopulates all the input fields if there are server side errors.

Once problem is that when I successfully submit the form and all the client side validation passes, my HTML that I have that is triggered by this code is hidden even tho the form didn't fully pass both server and client side validation.

So I went ahead and added a class called "is-submitted" via PHP to append to my  tag as soon as we have server side errors as shown below:

[image]

So now the form tag is as followed: `<form class="needs-validation is-submitted"></form>`

This is the error that I'm receiving now: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` which is because it can't find the 'resident' ID anymore since it's hidden on submission.

**What I need to achieve**: How can I use the existing code above to track whether there is a valid 'is-submitted' classname and then place it in the 'block' display so that the form is still displayed?

Comment: Hiding an element with CSS doesn't prevent `getElementById()` from finding it.

Comment: Try `<form id="contactForm" class="needs-validation is-submitted"></form>`

Comment: @zer00ne I posted an updated answer but there has to be a smaller and simpler solution.

Comment: @SLE You'll need to include the HTML, it's not clear what and where `#contactForm` and `#resident` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it figured out but there is no way that this will be my final answer - Is there a better way to simplify the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('resident') !== null) {
    function handler() {
        if (document.getElementById('resident').value !== 'CA') {
            formWrapperState.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            formWrapperState.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('resident').addEventListener('change', handler);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);
    handler();
} else if (document.getElementsByClassName('is-submitted')) {
    formWrapperState.style.display = 'block';
}
```

@zer00ne @Barmar